# Android TextView horizontal scroll does not work

Tags: java, android, scroll, textview

I read some thread in this topic, but I have not found the solution.
I would like to use the scrollHorizontally attribute on a TextView, but from Java code.

Here's what I tried:

```
        nameTextView = new TextView(context);
        nameTextView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 20);
        nameTextView.setId(R.id.header_text_id);
        nameTextView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.LEFT);
        nameTextView.setSingleLine();
        nameTextView.setHorizontallyScrolling(true);
        nameTextView.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
        nameTextView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        nameTextView.setMarqueeRepeatLimit(-1);
        nameTextView.setFocusable(true);

        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/robotocondensed.ttf");
        nameTextView.setTypeface(tf);
        nameTextView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
```

I set the text later. The text does not scroll, what can be the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 android:maxLines = "AN_INTEGER"

 android:scrollbars = "vertical"
```

Then set:

```
  yourTextView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod())
```

Comment: I added the last line (I can't use the scrollbars property from java, but I don't want to see it and used the setSingleLine() method) which results in if a move the text it starts to move, but does not do it automatically. How could I start it automatically?

Comment: I added nameTextView.requestFocus() and it works. Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score -1):

excelent article about how to make an horizontal scrollable textview in android, It works!!!

http://gabrielbl.com/2013/08/09/android-auto-horizontal-scrolling-marquee-textview/